# CUDA device heap memory for different applications

Tags: c++, cuda, heap-memory

I am trying to do an experiment. I have two applications. In one application I change the heap memory from 8MB default to 4MB and then I launch the kernel and finally I busy wait.
In another application I simply query for the size of heap memory of the device. The interesting thing is that for first application after kernel launch I continue to get 4MB while for other application I continue to get 8MB. Why so?

The code for application 1 is -

```
__global__ void kernelA()
{
    printf("I am running on kernelA\n");
}
int main()
{
    size_t size;
    cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize,100*sizeof(float));
    cudaDeviceGetLimit(&size, cudaLimitMallocHeapSize);
    printf("Heap size found to be %dn",(int)size);
    kernelA<<<1,10>>>();
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    while(1)
    {           
        cudaDeviceGetLimit(&size, cudaLimitMallocHeapSize);
        printf("Heap size found to be %d\n",(int)size); 
    }
}
```

The code for application 2 is -

```
int main()
{
    int k=1;
    size_t size;    
    for(k=1;k<1000000;k++)
    {
        cudaDeviceGetLimit(&size, cudaLimitMallocHeapSize);
        printf("Heap size found to be %d\n",(int)size);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CUDA runtime API calls only affect the CUcontext in the calling process that is associated with the specific device. cudaDevice* does not directly affect the state of other processes or other CUcontext in the same process that may be running on the same CUDA device.

Comment: does this means that different user applications get different heap memory. I mean when a different user application tries to access the GPU then does the driver creates a 8MB new heap memory from the global memory.